# Android center gravity is not working if container layout is in a scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, layout-gravity, android-gravity

I am creating a ProgressBar to be placed in the vertical center of a LinearLayout (other layouts will not work; I need to use a LinearLayout). Here is some code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

//add progressbar
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
progressBar.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(progressBar);
```

I have a ContainerView which will hold the LinearLayout created above. Something like this:

```
public class ContainerView extends ScrollView {
    public ContainerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
        addView(linearLayout);     //which is created in the snippet above
    }
}
```

If I extend ContainerView with LinearLayout, everything works fine.

If I extend ContainerView with ScrollView, ProgressBar is centered horizontally but not vertically.

What's the reason behind this dual behavior? My goal is to show a ProgressBar during the download of some data; once data is downloaded, I need to show it in the LinearLayout.

(Note: The reason for using ScrollView is that downloaded data may be too large to fit a small screen. This may seem like a use-case for ListView, but there are some other reasons that prevent me from using ListView.)

Comment: Doesn't work even with RelativeLayout. Parent ScrollView is the problem.

Comment: Please refer to the code above. I am adding the ProgressBar to LinearLayout and the LinearLayout is in ScrollView. Even if I replace the intermediary LinearLayout with RelativeLayout, that does not solve the problem.

Comment: I was asking you to do  something similar to what Gvs13 has mentioned in his answer :) I believe its correct isn't that working for you?

Comment: Hint: if you *tell* people not to downvote the question, lots of them will do exactly that. "Plz do not downvote" is a cue that the question probably needs to be downvoted. Either way, that is just noise that does not belong in a question. I have edited it out here and otherwise improved the clarity of your question. Please do not add it back in. There is nothing you can do about how people decide to vote. If the question is useful and clear, you will generally get more upvotes than downvotes, which makes up for it in the end. Complaining about it in the comments is also discouraged.

Comment: I never add such requests in my questions. This question is special. I read over 20 similar questions. I did not want people to assume it's one of them. Few people just copy code, and some downvote  - preventing future readers from taking it seriously. I was not complaining - I was just afraid of not getting a solution to my query because people did not even read my question.

Comment: If you are going to say "This is not a duplicate" then say **which** questions it is not a duplicate of and **why**. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "**including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.**

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318249/119775).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it working after setting the following attribute to my parent ScrollView :

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have this kind of structure;

```
<RelativeLayout>
 <ProgressBar/>      
  <ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
    ..
   </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Initially your `ProgressBar` will be invisible but once your downloading starts you can set it to visible state. And we can use `centerInParent` for `ProgressBar` as we have `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: So, we can't have a ProgressBar inside ScrollView ? I understand this would work, but this deepens my hierarchy for no good reason.

Comment: @slowAndSteady I am not an expert in android :) but I believe this is how scollview should behave :) Scrollview is just a window that shows different part of its hige content view on scroll :) Contentview's height is decided by the content you provide to it :) In this case you are providing just a progress bar with height and width as wrap content so content view's height = progress bar height :) So Though your gravity to center works because height of contentview = progress bar height it wont make any difference :) I hope I make sense I putting my view from my experience in iOS scrollView :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace

```
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

with

```
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP);
```